# Thread created inside a OSGi bundle cannot load classes from other bundles

Tags: multithreading, osgi, karaf

I have couple of OSGi bundles; am spinning a thread in one bundle and inside the run method, I am trying to create instance of a class from another bundle but it just fails, throws ClassNotFoundException

Bundle 1:

```
package com.test.bnd1;
 public Class A {
 }
```

pom.xml :

```
Export-package: com.test.bnd1.*
```

Bundle 2:

```
public com.test.bnd2;
public Class B {
   public void init() {
     MyThd thd = new MyThd();
     thd.start();
   }
}

public Class MyThd extends Thread {
   public void run() {
      A a = new A(); //throws ClassNotFoundException
   }
}
```

pom.xml :

```
Import-package: com.test.bnd1.*
```

blueprint.xml:

```
<bean id="testB" class="com.test.bnd2.B" init-method="init"/>
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

There are no headers in OSGi called `exports-package` or `imports-package`.

You need to use `Export-Package` and `Import-Package` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this [article](http://iocanel.blogspot.com/2012/07/apache-karaf-meets-apache-hbase.html?_sm_au_=iMVr4PN8SMspc8R5) I have reset the current thread's TCCL to the bundle class loader and got the classes from other bundles loaded. If anyone else has a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: I am not finding any other way!

Comment: Sorry but I'll state it again... you shouldn't have to do this. Are you sure you have posted your actual code, not some oversimplification of it?

Comment: that is certainly not the actual code but sure it depicts the problem. Setting the thread context class loader fixed the issue; that kind of tells me that even if there is one another way to fix, it has to be around the class loader.

Comment: Let me ask another way... does the code you have **actually posted** throw a ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: In fact I have tested with that exact code and it works fine with no ClassNotFoundException. So the problem must be in the code that you haven't posted.

Comment: it only depicts the problem, may not reproduce the problem. I will write sample program and will post

Comment: Yes, I think that is necessary. Something significant has clearly been lost in the depiction/simplification of the code.